# Find the text between bbCode

Tags: java, regex, bbcode

I'm trying to remove the BBCode from a String.

This is myString:

```
String wording = "Teststring 
[URL=\"http://www.test.ch/status\"]http://www.test.ch/status[/URL] [IMG]http://sit.corproot.net/uploads/659_untitled.png[/IMG] \n\n"
```

I've already tried this one:

```
  wording?.replaceAll("\\[URL=\".*\\](.*?)\\[/URL\\]", "")
```

My target string should be:

```
Teststring http://www.test.ch/status \n\n"
```

But when I run the code, it doesn't replace anything

What am I doing wrong?

Kind regards

Comment: why a `?` after wording?

Comment: I use Groovy Script. This is the savenavigation operator.

Comment: I don't think `/` needs to be escaped in RegEx, thus the closing BBTag is never matched. Verify by looking at input `[URL="asd"][\/URL]`.

Comment: @CollinG is `\n` means a newline character or a literal `\n` ?

Comment: \n is here a real string from a connector. but the gui does afterwords use it as newline. but you can ignore that. is just an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  String s = "Teststring URL=\"http://www.test.ch/status\"]http://www.test.ch/status[/URL] [IMG]http://sit.corproot.net/uploads/659_untitled.png[/IMG] \n\n";

  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?s)^(\\w+)[^\\[]+\\[URL=\"(.*)\"\\].*");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

  if (m.matches()) {
      System.out.println(String.format("%s %s \\n\\n", m.group(1), m.group(2)));
  }

}
```

Out:

```
Teststring http://www.test.ch/status \n\n
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex:

```
\s*\[URL=\\".*\](.*?)\[\/URL\]|\s*\[IMG\].*?\[\/IMG\]\s*
```

Java regex string would be,

```
"\\s*\\[URL=\\\\\".*\\](.*?)\\[\\/URL\\]|\\s*\\[IMG\\].*?\\[\\/IMG\\]\\s*"
```

Replacement string:

```
 $1
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/pF4dE6/2)